# WPF DataGridColumn Widths inside ListBox

Tags: wpf, datagrid, listbox, sizing

I have a ListBox that is databound to some data, and I would like there to be repeated DataGrids inside this.

I have found a strange anomaly when doing this, and hoping someone can help me out.

If I put the DataGrid together with ColumnWidths="*", it works fine.

If I put the DataGrid inside a ListBox, the columns are all tiny.

Here is a simple example I just whipped up in Blend:

```
<Window.Resources>
<SampleData:SampleDataSource x:Key="SampleDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}" >               
   <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
      <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
           ColumnWidth="*" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Property1}" Header="Property1"/>
      <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Property2}" Header="Property2"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
   </ListBox>       
</DockPanel>
```

This produces the following output:
[image: Bad, bad datagrid columns]

Anyone who felt like giving me a hand fixing this, I would be most grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `ColumnWidth="Auto"` or `ColumnWidth="SizeToHeader"` or `ColumnWidth="SizeToCells"` what layout are you lookg for?

Comment: Yes, I have tried all of them.

I would just like the Star (*) resizing to work as normal inside a listbox. If I set the column widths to absolute numbers (Width="200"), it works fine, but this isn't what I need unfortunately.

Comment: what layout are you looking for, all the above options show the whole column

Comment: The Star option without other qualifiers simply makes each column the same size in relationship to the grid. So, 5 columns will all be 1/5th the size of the datagrid.

Since there are going to be multiple DataGrids, having columns with different sizes would look odd.

If you want a better idea, take the sample code and just remove the Datagrid from the listbox and you'll see what it looks like.

Comment: do you need the HorizontalScrollBar? because you could disable it to allow the listbox to calculate its width, `<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`

Comment: That does work, thanks for that. I may need it for some columns with minimum size in the future.

Another solution I've found is :

<ListBox.Template>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <ItemsPresenter />
          </ControlTemplate>
        </ListBox.Template>

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem.  Try this:

```
    <ListBox>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <ItemsPresenter Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ListBox>
```